# how to predict the next event date in R

Tags: r

I have data with such format

```
lid=structure(list(data_user_create.order = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L), .Label = c("24.08.2017 10:26", 
"24.08.2017 10:27", "24.08.2017 10:28", "24.08.2017 10:29", "24.08.2017 10:30", 
"24.08.2017 10:31", "24.08.2017 10:32", "24.08.2017 10:34", "24.08.2017 10:37", 
"24.08.2017 10:38", "24.08.2017 10:39", "24.08.2017 10:40", "24.08.2017 10:42", 
"24.08.2017 10:43", "24.08.2017 10:44", "24.08.2017 10:45", "24.08.2017 10:46", 
"24.08.2017 10:47", "24.08.2017 10:48", "24.08.2017 10:49", "24.08.2017 10:50", 
"24.08.2017 10:51", "24.08.2017 10:52", "24.08.2017 10:53", "24.08.2017 10:54", 
"24.08.2017 10:55", "24.08.2017 10:56", "24.08.2017 10:57", "24.08.2017 10:58", 
"24.08.2017 10:59", "24.08.2017 11:00", "24.08.2017 11:01", "24.08.2017 11:02", 
"24.08.2017 11:03", "24.08.2017 11:04"), class = "factor"), goods = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Ecoslim", "Hammer of Thor"
), class = "factor"), id_users = 1:119), .Names = c("data_user_create.order", 
"goods", "id_users"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-119L))
```

`data_user_create_create.order` is when person create order in shop
`goods` is type of goods
`id_users` is id_users it not important column.
different people at the same time can order the same products.

So for each goods I must create forecast to predict date of event in format dd-mm-yyyy-hh-mm-ss

My attempt:

```
library("forecast")
my_forecast <- function(x){
  model <- arima(x, order = c(1, 1, 1))
  fcast <- forecast(model, 2)
  return(fcast)
}

#applying it as follows

lapply(lid[1], my_forecast)
```

and error:

```
Error in arima(x, order = c(1, 1, 1)) : non-stationary AR part from CSS
```

i think `arima` can't forecast date as fact of event, cause I try forecast not metric var, but the next date when event will occur (person create order)
i.e. desired output.

```
date person createon  type of goods
24.08.2017  11:04:02     Ecoslim
24.08.2017  11:04:38      Ecoslim
24.08.2017  11:05:45        Ecoslim 
24.08.2017  11:04:02     pillow
24.08.2017  11:04:38      pillow
24.08.2017  11:05:45        pillow
```

How can I forecast date of event?

Comment: If you are able to add a variable, you could predict the days to next person create order and then use that days to add to the last date and get your date as an output.

Comment: Consider predicting purchase during a period, say during two weeks from last order, instead of an exact date. Also consider the format (I am looking at the minutes & seconds).

Comment: @jessi, may i create binary variable 0  purchse after oerder create, 1 not purchase after order by person?

Comment: That could work for a different conceptualization of your problem. I was suggesting that you try to predict the change in days instead of the actual date. If you have a binary variable, you may want to look at the hazard rate model.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would use a regression model for something like this.

https://www.machinelearningplus.com/machine-learning/complete-introduction-linear-regression-r/

Or, consider using time series forecasting.

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/time-series-forecasting-using-r

But...your data set looks pretty sparse.  You have IDs, which are really useless in the ML world, plus dates and goods.  What is the logic?  A human would have to know how to make a prediction before you can train a machine to be able to make the prediction (supervised learning).